# Android Application Layout Help

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Hi does anyone know how to add/change the colour of the application layout.  It is a .xml file

I'd like to add a border and change the background colour.  There are also text fields in there, is it possible to add a border/border colour to the text fields.

I am a novice by the way!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are new to this, you should use Eclipse with Android SDK plugin. In Eclipse, you can use the visual layout editor which will give you a fast and easy answer to your questions, and even more.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I use eclipse, but I'd like to use code.

is there something like android:layout_width="wrap_content">
                        android:layout_colour e.tc?

Comment: That's my point exactly: Use the visual editor to do what you want, then switch back to xml view, and observe how it is written.

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid the visual editor doesn't show much infomation about editing text sizes/colour and such?

Comment: Right click an item, highlight the properties menu, and go down with the bottom arrow in the menu. I just checked and there are TextSize and TextColor properties.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.  I have one issue though.  When I try to change the background colour, for example:
android:background="#ffffff"

It only changes the colour around the text, not the entire background.I have tried to inserting this code in different places to see what happens but I get the same result.  I even inserted the code in the linearlayout bit and It still did the same.  Not sure where I'm going wrong?  Thanks

Comment: It's possible the visual editor has a few bugs, but at least you found the name of the properties you were looking for. For your particular problem, set the android:background="#fffff" property directly in the xml code, and in the top level linear layout. It will work.

Comment: I put it right under the declaration bit to no avail :/
Here's a screenshot.
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/508/scrn1t.jpg/

thanks.

Comment: I just tested and it works with me. I don't know what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score -1):

android:background="#ffffff" for white bg .

2 b vry frank 4 a beginner, developer site or other tutorials will prove much more effective den putting questions here .